# Add segment in oh-my-posh if folder name contains certain letters

Tags: oh-my-posh

I want to dynamically add a segment based on the name of the current directory, here e.g., the `abc`.

[image: oh-my-posh example]

If the directory name is `abc`, then I want to add a segment showing an icon, e.g., a house, between the git information and the blue success indicator.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [text](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/text) segment and the following [template](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/configuration/templates):

`{{ if contains .Folder \"abc\" }}icon{{ end }}`

```json
{
  "type": "text",
  "style": "plain",
  "foreground": "#E06C75",
  "template": " {{ if contains .Folder \"abc\" }}icon{{ end }} "
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does somehow not work; If I remove the ``if``, I get to see the 'icon' when I cd into ``abc``. But when I add the ``if`` condition, it is no longer displayed, altought I am still in ``abc``.

Comment: OK, it works when I use ``"template": " {{ if contains .Folder \"abc\" }}icon{{ end }} "``

Comment: @user69453 also correct, I'll adjust my answer!